# why unnecessary values overriding when calculating total in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hive

when i try to increase the quantity the total amount showing big numbers and when i exit the page and reenter it showing correct out put why this happenning...?[this happens when i increase or decrease the quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2obvb.png)

[this happens when i exit the page and reenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0osME.png)

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:appnew/src/hivedatabase/cart_model.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:appnew/src/widgets/totalprice.dart';

List<String> compnme = List();
List<String> compqnt = List();

class CartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartPageState createState() => _CartPageState();
}

class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {
  double sum = 0;

  final cartBox = Hive.box('carts');
  final totBox = Hive.box('tot');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        title: Text(
          'Cart',
        ),
      ),
      body: _buildListView(),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: _buildtotal(),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: new MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final cartBox = Hive.box('carts');
                cartBox.clear();
                compnme.clear();
                compqnt.clear();
                totBox.clear();
              },
              child: new Text(
                "Check Out",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    return WatchBoxBuilder(
      box: Hive.box('carts'),
      builder: (context, cartBox) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: cartBox.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final cartModel = cartBox.getAt(index) as CartModel;
            double iprice = double.parse(cartModel.price);
            double nprice = 0;
            int iquant = int.parse(cartModel.quantitys);

            return Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: Container(
                height: 130,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 129,
                      width: 125,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(cartModel.img),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 130,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 5),
                            child: Text(
                              cartModel.pname,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 4, 0, 3),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 160,
                              child: Text(cartModel.curquant,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1, 25, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Rs." + cartModel.price,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 19, color: Colors.black54)),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 77, 19, 2),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 90,
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle,
                                size: 35, color: Colors.green[300]),
                            onPressed: () {
                              iquant++;
                              nprice = iprice + (iprice / (iquant - 1));
                              cartBox.putAt(
                                  index,
                                  CartModel(
                                      cartModel.pname,
                                      cartModel.curquant,
                                      cartModel.img,
                                      nprice.toString(),
                                      iquant.toString()));
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 77, 0, 2),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 90,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                          maxRadius: 16,
                          child: Text(cartModel.quantitys),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(19, 77, 0, 2),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 90,
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
                                size: 35, color: Colors.redAccent),
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (iquant == 1) {
                                cartBox.deleteAt(index);
                                print(compnme[index]);
                                compnme.removeAt(index);
                                compqnt.removeAt(index);
                              } else {
                                iquant--;
                                nprice = iprice - (iprice / (iquant + 1));

                                cartBox.putAt(
                                    index,
                                    CartModel(
                                        cartModel.pname,
                                        cartModel.curquant,
                                        cartModel.img,
                                        nprice.toString(),
                                        iquant.toString()));
                              }
                            }),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildtotal() {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    return WatchBoxBuilder(
        box: Hive.box('carts'),
        builder: (context, cartBox) {
          for (int i = 0; i < cartBox.length; i++) {
            final cartModel = cartBox.getAt(i) as CartModel;
            double iprice = double.parse(cartModel.price);
            sum += iprice;
            print(sum);
          }
          return ListTile(
            title: new Text("total:", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            subtitle: new Text(sum.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 16,
                )),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

i tried adding setState() in buttons and functions but it didnt worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign zero each time in _buildtotal() method

```
 Widget _buildtotal() {
sum=0;//This will reset sum value zero before re-calculating total
// ignore: deprecated_member_use
return WatchBoxBuilder(
    box: Hive.box('carts'),
    builder: (context, cartBox) {
      for (int i = 0; i < cartBox.length; i++) {
        final cartModel = cartBox.getAt(i) as CartModel;
        double iprice = double.parse(cartModel.price);
        sum += iprice;
        print(sum);
      }
      return ListTile(
        title: new Text("total:", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        subtitle: new Text(sum.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16,
            )),
      );
    });
```

}